# Hash Map Key comparisons

Tags: java, hashmap

I am making a hashmap by reading a particular section in the input file. However the input files do not have a standard indentation format, ie, some of the lines start with a # characters , while some do not. I am supposed to capture the key and value from the file. 
Here is my code:

```
String schedule = "config [\"Sql\"] = \\";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f1);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {

            sCurrentLine = scanner.nextLine();

            if (sCurrentLine.contains(schedule)) {
                System.out.println(f1.getFileName()+" Contains a schedule");    
                scheduleFlag = true;
            }
            else if(sCurrentLine.contains("config [")) {
                scheduleFlag = false;
            }
            if(sCurrentLine.trim().startsWith("(")  && sCurrentLine.trim().endsWith(",") && scheduleFlag == true) {
                scheduleName = sCurrentLine;
                scheduleName = scheduleName.substring(scheduleName.indexOf('"')+1, scheduleName.lastIndexOf('"'));
                //writer.write(scheduleName);
                out.write(scheduleName.getBytes());
                HashMapping = true;

            }
            if(scheduleFlag == true && HashMapping == true) {
                String [] values = sCurrentLine.split(":");

                if (values.length < 2);
                else {
                hm.put(values[0], values[1]);
                }
            }
```

Here is a section of input file :

```
#config ["Sql"] = \
#[
#   ("KB",
#       {
#           "subsystem":              "DMN",
#           "enabled":                "0",
#           "freqtype":               "4",
     }
```

I just want the string including the double quotes in my key, ignoring the # character(which may or may not be present in a given file). Is there any way?

Comment: Just remove all `#` characters with `str.replaceAll('#','')`

Comment: @Nikem Maybe use `replaceAll("^\\s*#", "")` to only replace `#` at beginning of line?

Comment: I would suggest you getting a useful file format. Which software is exporting data like this?

Comment: @tobias_k Exactly, I just want to replace # at the beginning of the line. But your expression isn't working !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for matches of a regular expression like

```
"[^"]*"
```

You can iterate over the elements in quotation marks by something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(yourInputString);

while (matcher.find())
  {
      //do something with the match

  }
```

Comment: I did not get you.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: How does your regex remove or ignore the # character?

Comment: Do you mean str.replaceAll("[^"]*","")

Comment: No, I mean the following: Take the input String and search for all matches of the stated regex. Then you get a collection of all elements in quotation marks. Iterating through this collection allows you to fill your map.

Comment: I'm trying to split the line string wiht your given regex. Doesn't work.
I'm a newbie, sorry for the troubles.